# Interesting bug in PHP

Tags: php

Here in the following block of program it prints 2  instead of 1.

```
<?php
 f(0, $$var);
 $x = 1;
 $y = 2;
 echo $x;
 function f($a, $b) {}
?>
```

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE 1**
This information has been get from http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/php/95595

**UPDATE 2**
By posting this question mainly I just wanted to 1) inform others about this bug, 2) get ideas of different users about the reasons of why this happens.

Comment: Prints `2` for me, I can reproduce it on PHP 5.3 on Windows. If I however prepend anything to the `f()` call, it will print out 1. Looks like a real bug, interesting. It's obviously the non-existant `$$var`  but why?

Comment: Actually it outputs 1: http://codepad.org/4kizNzpX

Comment: @Bakhtiyor: What is your PHP version and it is running in what OS?

Comment: I use PHP 5.3.1 on Windows 7.

Comment: This is not the place for this. It is not a programing question.

Comment: Has anyone tried to figure out why it's returning 2? Try changing the values of the numbers, running var_dumps, does it always return 2 or does it return the value of '$y'? Just saying "Oh it's a bug" is just stupid.

Comment: @animuson: Because `$$var` is essentially doing `$(null)`, which is messing up the variables heap in PHP. You cannot have a variable who's name is a `NULL` type.

Comment: Andrew Moore, if it is not a programming question then what kind of question is it? I have posted this question just to inform others about this bug and get ideas about the reasons why it happens so.

Comment: @Bakhtiyor: **It ain't a question at all.** This is an invitation to a discussion about a bug and quite frankly, a pretty bad invitation at that. You didn't even point in which direction you want the discussion to progress? Can you reproduce it? What may be the reason behind it? It doesn't matter anyway. [Read the FAQ: "Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion."](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: Well, the corresponding bug report http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52001 is quite recent (about 8 hours ago). And unless someone is into the internals of PHP, I don’t think this the right place for such kind of questions.

Comment: I didn't see anywhere on PHP's variable variables page that you can't use NULL there... When I run `var_dump(${NULL})` I get NULL back, as expected. There is no error or anything for it. I also tried `var_dump(${""})` and `var_dump(${0})` which both put out NULL as well.

Comment: Bug was already filed, no question, what does it do here, besides being quaint? On a side note: throws an E_NOTICE on debian 64 / 5.3.2-1. Now let's close the non-question.

Answer (score 0):

Prints `2` on Mac. (PHP 5.3.1)